# How to use "in" or "on" with nouns?

Tags: prepositions, nouns

I'm always confused by this and can't find it anywhere. Here's an example of what I mean: (literature here in context of academic literature, such as journals, proceedings, etc.)

> In the literature ...

or

> On the literature ...

Another one:

> ... an overview on the advances of ...

or

> ... an overview in the advances of ...

Someone care to say which ones are correct and why?

Comment: This question requires a critical overview of all the implications.

Comment: Is there any way that I can narrow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Literature

Words are contained **in** sentences. Meaning resides **within** sentences. Sentences are **within** paragraphs. Paragraphs are **in** articles or **in** chapters **in** books. articles, books and other writings make up literature.

If something was *on* literature it would be external to it. "Essays on the Literature of Sao Tome and Principe."

### Overview

This is a conjunction of *over* and *view* suggesting the view from a high place where one can look over nearby obstacles to see the whole surrounding context. It uses, as a metaphor, the visual meaning of *view* (rather than it's meaning as a synonym of *opinion* for example)

We most often use *of* with *view* so this carries across to *overview*. Sometimes we use *into* with *view* but this isn't appropriate here because an overview isn't concerned with looking primarily at detail inside something.

Answer (score 3):

If there are portions of the literature that you are referencing in order to make or support a point, you would say "In the literature regarding this topic, we can see...", because you are looking at various passages inside the literature as a whole.

For "overview", the correct preposition to use is "of":

> This is an overview of the advances of Dr. Bork in the field of Podiatric Phalangeal Ordinal Dactyl Scansion Patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In all languages generally, the distribution of prepositions is highly idiomatic and subject to particular prepositions being associated with particular nouns or quite narrow concepts; it's difficult to give simple rules that will work in all cases.

That said, as a native English speaker, I'd say that the two cases here are quite conceptually different to me: "in" in the first case is more or less synonymous with "within", and-- in case this helps-- there's almost a figurative idea of picturing yourself "inside" a box containing information.

In the second case, "overview" functions as a "picture" noun (like "a photo/image/collage/snapshot/montage/film of ..."), where English tends to prefer "of". Coincidentally, some languages might allow the same preposition in these two cases, but they're essentially different constructions.